# SQL in PHPMYADMIN

Tags: mysql

I help with an SQL (using phpmyadmin) to join these tables and create a CLUB MEMBERSHIP list for a particular club, however I need to indicate whether the member is a club president, vice president,etc or just an ordinary member:

```
CLUBS: CLUBID,PRESIDENTID(memberID),VICEPRESIDENTID(memberID),TREASURER(memberID),
SECRETARY(MemberID)

MEMBERS_CLUB:  
MEMBERID,CLUBID 

MEMBERS:
MEMBERID, NAME,ADDRESS
```

Comment: do you have many clubs?

Comment: your table structure makes little sense.  It is unclear as to why you have memberID  4 times on one table.  Also if you have a id for each role (e.g. president), is there a separate table holding the title?     Or do you mean that those roles are just indicators?

Comment: Hi ALex, thanks for responding. Yes many clubs and the clubs table holds the member id for president,vicepresident,treasurer and secretary. How would you suggest I structure the table?

Comment: There is no table holding the title , I wish to do this via the sql

Answer (score 0):

There are probably half a dozen ways to solve this, and you certainly could come up with a way to make this table structure work for you, but it's probably not going to be pretty. Part of making this work well is determining what information you need to get out as well as store in the database. In this structure, it's very hard to get the member's officer status from their name, so we can improve that by changing your structure. On the other hand, if all you ever needed was a list of officers for each club, your current structure would be okay.

You could add a "member status" field to `MEMBERS_CLUB` (and remove the four corresponding columns from `CLUBS`). Each member gets a row for each club or position they hold.

```
SELECT `MEMBERS`.`NAME`, `MEMBERS_CLUB`.`STATUS`, `CLUBS`.`CLUBID`
  FROM `MEMBERS`, `MEMBERS_CLUB`, `CLUBS`
  WHERE `MEMBERS`.`MEMBERID` = `MEMBERS_CLUB`.`MEMBERID`
```

which is close but gives us duplicates if there are duplicates in the table, for instance if you have two entries for Bob, one listing him as president and one listing him as secretary. By using GROUP_CONCAT() we can accomplish exactly what you are looking for while dealing properly with duplicated names:

```
SELECT `MEMBERS`.`NAME`, GROUP_CONCAT(`MEMBERS_CLUB`.`STATUS`), `CLUBS`.`CLUBID`
  FROM `MEMBERS`, `MEMBERS_CLUB`, `CLUBS`
  WHERE `MEMBERS`.`MEMBERID` = `MEMBERS_CLUB`.`MEMBERID`
  GROUP BY `NAME`
```